# How to execute bash script in a loop which iterations will be written from a keyboard

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which tests funcionality of the program. I run this script simply by using `./name_of_script`. 
But I want to have a opportunity to add number of iterations in the same command, 
like this:

```
./name_of_script number_of_iterations
```

Moreover, if the number_of_iterations won't be written in a command, it should be equal 1 by default.

I write some code but it doesnt work as good as I want.

```
read iterations 

for(( w=1; w <= iterations; w++))
do
.
.
.
done
```

It doesnt provide determination of iterations in one command and waits for me to write it in a second line.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
iterations=${1:-1}
#            ^  ^
#            |  |-----------
#            |             |
#      First parameter     Default if first parameter is unset
for(( w=1; w <= iterations; w++))
do
    echo "Hello World $w"
done
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers